# Can't get Pi/Debian to renew DHCP on boot

Tags: networking, dhcp, raspberry-pi

I recently tried getting my Raspberri Pi/Debian going with WiFi. That was a bust and seemed shaky, so I want to go back to regular wired.

But not I cannot get a eth0 connection going for some reason.

I've put back in the defaults in to my network conf and supplemental conf. But I'm unable to get an IP address automatically assigned on boot. `sudo dhclient -v eth0` gets everything running fine. However it doesn't stick on boot. I've tried adding that to `/etc/rc.local` but it won't work on boot -- I have to manually edit.

Here is the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Comment: Which OS do you have? Raspbian? Which one, Jessie? Starting with Jessie, the dhcp client is a daemon provided by dhcpcd

Comment: @ripat yes, Raspbian compiled: Feb 2 2015. Not sure what name is assigned like Jessie--haven't seen that before.

Comment: `cat /etc/debian_version` will give you the Raspbian version running on your Pi. On Raspbian 8, the DHCP requests are done by the dhcpcd daemon which should be configured accordingly. (`man dhcpcd.conf`)

Comment: @ripat thank you. I'm at version 7.8.